# Which domain name is best?

Tags: domains, wordpress, url, blog

I am planning to buy a new domain for my blog. My name is Joel. If I choose a domain as `joelblog.com` or something like that will it be nice? Or should I choose a name like `expertthings.com` or something like that which doesn't contain my name?

Comment: Which will be your target audience?

Comment: I am writing blog about technology.

Comment: Whatever your theme, which will be your visitors? Possible clients? Do you create a blog by passion or for business?

Comment: By passion and also for adsense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding comments under your question, I think a good option would be to choose a domain name like `joelblog.com` because you create a blog by passion. Choosing a domain name like `expertthings.com` could be great if your target audience are possible clients but it's not your case.

However, you can buy the domain name you prefer, it's just a question of taste.

If you already have a site, the best option is most probably to create a subdomain like `blog.yoursite.com` because subdomains have been specifically created for this.

Comment: but i have a domain. That is like firstname-lastname.com. I think slash (-) is not looking good for a domain. What is your opinion?

Comment: In that way, the best option is to create a subdomain like `blog.firstname-lastname.com`. Subdomains have been created specifically for this.